# Impregnating polyethylene with oil using pressure cooker?

Tags: polymers, pressure

I have some polyethylene spiral wrap that I'm hoping to impregnate with citrus oil as an animal deterrent.

Wikipedia says that polyethylene plastic will pass through "flavourings" fairly easily. It's melting point for the grade I have seems to be around 100C.

Do you think that placing polyethylene and citrus oil into a pressure cooker and keeping the temperature to around 90C for a few hours would infuse the polymer with enough of the flavour compounds from the oils to have any reasonable effect?

Or would it just be as effective to leave the polyethylene in an oil bath and leave it sealed at room temperature for a month or so?

Comment: Will sure diffuse in and also come out again, but to what extent, and if it works on whatever animal you want to set it on (and how long), you´ll have to try. Im not sure what exactly "spiral wrap" is, but I´m also not sure you´ll like its mechanical properties after it was at 90°C .

Comment: A Google search of "polyethylene spiral wrap" should give you a pretty good idea of the sort of products I'm referring to. If the melting temperature is at least 100C, then, assuming there is no significant mechanical load on it while it is at 90C, and it is allowed to cool down properly, then what kind of mechanic strength can I expect?

Comment: The oil likely will; damage the pressure-cooker gasket. Just leave the wrap submerged in a container, and if you wish, warm *gently* in a hot-water bath.